# Find a combinatorial proof to 10!=7!6!

Tags: combinatorics, group-theory, factorial, symmetric-groups

Prove combinatorically that $ 10!=7!6! $.

By "prove combinatorically" i mean everything that does not pass by computing $10!,7!,6! $ or some factors of them. This is clearly equivalent to find a bijection (or prove it does exist) between $S_{10}$ and $ S_7 \times S_6 $ where $S_n$ is the symmetric group of order $n$.

Comment: A possible reduction would be to observe $S_{10}$ is bijective with $K_{10,3} \times S_7$ where $K_{10,3}$ is the set of one-to-one functions $[3] \to [10]$ (which is an encoding of choosing 3 distinct elements of $[10]$ with order of the 3 being significant).  So, it would be sufficient to show $K_{10,3}$ is bijective with $S_6$.

Comment: @Shaun i tried using group theory and i got same result as Nilknarf, with also deep inside the same solution. Defining $ \phi(x) : S_{10} \rightarrow S_7 $ such that $\phi$ takes $x \in S_{10} $ a permutation of numbers $(1,2,3...10) $ and mantaining the same order it cancels numbers $ 8,9,10$, now by first theorem of group homomorphism we get $ \frac{S_{10}}{ker(\phi)} \sim S_{7} $ and it's clear that $ |ker(\phi)|=8\cdot 9\cdot 10 $ wich is same result below

Answer (score 5):

Here is a combinatorial proof:

Suppose we have ten people and we want to find how many ways to arrange them in a straight line. The answer is obviously $10!$, because we can choose from ten people for the first spot, nine for the second, and so on.

Now consider choosing an order in a different way. Let us put $7$ people in a line, then insert the remaining $3$. There are $7!$ ways to make the $7$-person line, and then there are $8\cdot9\cdot10$ ways to insert the last three people. Thus the total number of ways is
$$7!\cdot8\cdot9\cdot10$$
and
$$10!=7!\cdot8\cdot9\cdot10$$
Now all you need to do is prove that $\cdot8\cdot9\cdot10=6!$. Can you do that by following my example for the first half of the problem?

Comment: This basically says $10 ! = 7! (8 \cdot 9 \cdot 10) $ and $(8 \cdot 9 \cdot 10) = 6!$. Only the first equality is "proved combinatorically",

Comment: I do not think that it is an answer.

Comment: Only using the fact that $ 3!=6 $ we have that $ 10!=7!6! $ is equivalent to $ \binom{10}{3}=5! $, don't know if this is helpful